# Basic NGINX url rewriting

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a domain with some get arguments.
Lets say 3, so we have this: www.domain.com/?a1=x&a2=y&a3=z
And I want to rewrite this to this: www.domain.com/x/y/z/

This is what I have till now

```
rewrite ^/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/$ /index.php?a1=$1&a2=$2&a3=$3? last;
```

And this pretty much does the job when all arguments are filled in.
But! When you leave 1 argument out you get a 404.

So any NGINX expert who can help me rewriting the url?
I also need to exclude .js & .css files and can't do this for some reason as well.

Kind regards,
WouterDS

Comment: There is a very trivial way to do this with `try_files`, but only if you're using the front-controller pattern, or with changes to how you parse your query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're xyz variables are alpha numeric you could just do something like:

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ /index.php?a1=$1&a2=$2&a3=$3? last;
```

Comment: That fixed it for me.

But I still can't exclude my css & js.